# Views dependant on UserDefaults not updating on change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I have a class that records the state of a toggle and a selection of a picker into UserDefaults

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldSort: Bool {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(shouldSort, forKey: "shouldSort")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var sortKey: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(sortKey, forKey: "sortKey")
        }
    }
    
    public var sortKeys = ["alphabetical", "length", "newest", "oldest"]
    
    init() {
        self.shouldSort = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "shouldSort") as? Bool ?? true
        self.sortKey = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "sortKey") as? String ?? "Name"
    }
}
```

On my settings page I use the following code

```swift
@ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

...

Toggle(isOn: $userSettings.shouldSort, label: {Text("Sort Books")})

Picker(selection: $userSettings.sortKey, label: Text("Sort By"), content: {
                            ForEach(userSettings.sortKeys, id: \.self){ key in
                                Text(key)
                            }
                        })
```

This code changes the value just fine because if I close and open the app, the views update based on the data. I am reading the data with

```swift
@State var sorted =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "shouldSort")
@State var sort =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sortKey")
```

in my content view. (shouldSort calls a function to sort if true and sortKey determines how the data is sorted)

Am I reading the data wrong with the @State variable (can @State even detect changes in state of UserDefaults)?

Comment: No, state does not track UserDefaults automatically and it is not appropriate instrument for that. UserSettings above is good for that, you can use it as EnvironmentObject injected at root to have access to it in any view where needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget all what you learnt about UserDefaults in UIKit and say Hello to AppStorage in SwiftUI, use this Codes:

```
@AppStorage("shouldSort") var sorted: Bool = false
@AppStorage("sortKey") var sort: String = ""
```

Comment: Be caution, AppStorage is available only from SwiftUI 2.0. PO might need compatibility with iOS 13.

Comment: Does the AppStorage wrapper only read values or does it write values as well? If it writes values, do I still need my ObservableObject?

Comment: @Asperi , I'm using the new SwiftUI lifecycle so my app is anyways only iOS 14 friendly

Comment: @ArnavMotwani! Do not Worry, it work just fine! Write and Read! otherwise it has No usage! do not Obseve it, it work by itself. it knows when you update new value, it will be refunded after closing app!